# Data Pump export using cloud shell

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, datapump, expdp, oracle-cloud-shell

I am trying to export schema using data pump on Oracle Cloud Autonomous database.

I am using cloud shell to export schema.

When I tried to do the final step:

```
expdp admin/password@DB_HIGH schemas=SCHEMA_NAME directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=exp%U.dmp filesize=1G logfile=expot.log
```

I got

```
UDE-12154: operation generated ORACLE error 12154 ORA-12154: 
TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Do I need Oracle instant client to do export?

Comment: Has your password got a space in it, or maybe a dollar sign (that happens to be follow by characters than mean an environment variable is used); or did you introduce a space between the password and the TNS alias?

Comment: Password contain numbers and "!" sign

Comment: OK, pling could be the issue - it could be substituting a command (with a space) from your shell history. If you 'echo password' with your actual password you should see how it was expanded/replaced. Can you do `set +H` and try it again?

Comment: I changed the password, now I got UDE-12154: operation generated ORACLE error 12154
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: I can connect with the same tns entry

Comment: You can connect with`sqlplus admin/password@DB_HIGH`, from the same shell session? ANd sqlplus and expdp are from the same Oracle client? The error means DB_HIGH isn't in the tnsnames.ora file you're using, so if it works for one it will work for both.

Comment: Yes I can connect to SQLPLUS, but can't run expdp

Comment: To rule out issues with the password try `expdp admin@DB_HIGH ...` and let it prompt for the password.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Same error, after I enter the password

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle client code uses one of three ways to look up connect data:

A flat file named tnsnames.ora
Oracle Names service
LDAP

When the complete ORA-12154 error appears with the text line, your program has found a working Oracle client install. However, the specified Oracle service is not listed in tnsnames.ora, Oracle Names or LDAP.

The first step in the troubleshooting process is to determine which name resolution method is deployed at your site. Most sites use tnsnames.ora, but enough use Oracle Names and LDAP, so it’s best to confirm this information.

If you are not the database administrator, get in touch with the people managing your Oracle systems and find out which method you should be using. They may be able to guide you in fixing the problem in accordance with your site’s standards.

The client code decides which mechanism to use based on the file sqlnet.ora. This file and tnsnames can usually both be found in the Oracle install directory (“ORACLE_HOME”), under network/admin/. This location may be overridden with the environment variable TNS_ADMIN.

If the sqlnet.ora file does not exist or does not specify a resolution method, then Oracle Net uses tnsnames.ora.

Example locations of Oracle networking files include:

```
Windows

ORANTNET80ADMIN
ORACLEORA81NETWORKADMIN
ORAWIN95NETWORKADMIN
ORAWINNETWORKADMIN
 

UNIX / Linux

$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/
/etc/
/var/opt/oracle/
```

If you fix the naming issues, but you still see the ORA-12154 error, check the Oracle service to confirm that it’s available for connections. A power outage, server failure, or network connectivity issue will make this resource inaccessible. It’s also possible that scheduled maintenance or repairs of an unrelated Oracle issue may take that resource temporarily offline.
Thanks